# Jenkins:Send mail based on execute shell script condition

Tags: jenkins, email-ext, jenkins-email-ext

I have below script in Jenkins

```
if diff file1.txt file2.txt > file3.txt ; then
  echo "no difference"
else
  <need to send email notitication>
fi
```

I heard like we can achieve this using 'Email-ext plugin', I have plugin installed in my Jenkins.
Could any one can explain that how to use Email-ext plugin to send mail based on script condition.

Answer (score 0):

hi you can refer to [this](https://www.360logica.com/blog/email-notification-in-jenkins/) link for detailed steps to configure email template. In your pipeline script you can add below step to get notification:

```
emailext body: ''
    '${SCRIPT, template="groovy-html.template"}'
    '', subject: "${env.JOB_NAME} - Build # ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} - Successful",
      mimeType: 'text/html', to: "email list"
```

The groovy-html.template is default template which you can use or write your own content in email body and subject.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please explain the script, am getting error     "+ emailext body: ''
/mnt/apache-tomcat-7.0.26/temp/hudson6735116595060486738.sh: line 6: emailext: command not found"

Comment: you have to install emailext plugin

Comment: I already have installed 'Email Extension Plugin 2.0' in jenkins

Comment: Can you share how you are using emailext in your jenkins. It can be used in jenkins pipeline script.

Comment: refer this [link](https://www.360logica.com/blog/email-notification-in-jenkins/) for email ext plugin usage in free style job